# Double layer of device mapper - customising dm-crypt

Tags: encryption, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-mapper

**Is it possible to create a device mapper over another device mapper?**

I need to apply some checks in addition to encrypting the data on disk. So, I thought of creating a mapper (for additional checks) over the mapper created by **dm-crypt** and use new mapper's ioctl for applying those checks.

The dm-crypt created a mapper (say *crypt_mapper*) with starting sector and length as, say, 0 and 20000.

When I created a new mapper over this, the system crashes. There are no logs in dmesg.

```
echo 0 20000 access_target /dev/mapper/crypt_mapper 0 | dmsetup create access_mapper.
```

Comment: You can try netconsole to view logs

Comment: Thanks. There were some sector related errors in /var/log/messages. Those helped me check the size of mapper.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.

Didn't know that dm-crypt changes (reduces) the total size. It needs to store crypt headers.

```
# blockdev --getsize /dev/loop7
20000
# blockdev --getsize /dev/mapper/crypt_mapper
15904
```

I was creating the new mapper length over 20000 instead of 15904.